# Parsing iTunes RSS in R

Tags: xml, r, xml-parsing, rss

I'm trying to parse the iTunes top 100 in R and spit out artist, song etc. but I'm having issues with the XML file, I guess.  I was able to easily get useable data with Billboard's RSS (http://www1.billboard.com/rss/charts/hot-100)

```
GetBillboard <- function() {

  hot.100 <- xmlTreeParse("http://www1.billboard.com/rss/charts/hot-100")
  hot.100 <- xpathApply(xmlRoot(hot.100), "//item")

  top.songs <- character(length(hot.100))

  for(i in 1:length(hot.100)) {
    top.songs[i] <- xmlSApply(hot.100[[i]], xmlValue)[3]
  }
  return(top.songs)

}
```

Trying similar strategies with iTunes, though (https://itunes.apple.com/us/rss/topmusicvideos/limit=100/explicit=true/xml)

```
GetITunes <- function() {
  itunes.raw <- getURL("https://itunes.apple.com/us/rss/topmusicvideos/limit=100/explicit=true/xml")
  itunes.xml <- xmlTreeParse(itunes.raw)
  top.vids <- xpathApply(xmlRoot(itunes.xml), "//entry")
  return(top.vids)
}
```

I just get nonsense:

```
> m <- GetITunes()
> m
list()
attr(,"class")
[1] "XMLNodeSet"
>
```

I'm guessing it's the formatting of the XML file.  How can I get these iTunes data to fall into a similar structure as the data from Billboard at this point in the first function?

```
hot.100 <- xpathApply(xmlRoot(hot.100), "//item")
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your XML document has a default namespace and you are not taking that into consideration in your xpath. Unfortunately, when there is a default namespace, you need to be explicit about using that in your xpath. This should work

```
xpathApply(xmlRoot(itunes.xml), "//d:entry", 
    namespaces=c(d="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"))
```

Here we arbitrarily choose `d` to point to the default namespace used in the XML document and then use that prefix in our xpath expression.

Comment: This is closer, but I get a lot of "Namespace prefix im on artist is not defined" errors.  I'm guessing I need to use an argument to point im: somewhere, but my experience with XML is ... well, I looked at it for the first time today!

Comment: I tried:

xpathApply(xmlRoot(itunes.xml), "//d:entry", 
                         namespaces=c(d="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom", 
                                      im="http://itunes.apple.com/rss"))

But I'm still getting "Namespace prefix im ... is not defined."

Comment: That's not really an error so much as a warning. The problem is you are extracting a node where the namespace is no longer defined. It shouldn't impact your ability to process the node. But if you use `xmlParse` rather than `xmlTreeParse` you shouldn't get that warning.

Comment: Yeah, I'm able to get things to work now. I managed to extract what I needed after `xmlTreeParse` using method that doesn't seem to work with `xmlParse`, so I'll just live with the warnings for now. Thanks!